# "Error: One or more projects in the solution were not loaded correctly" particularly for Windows7

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2010

I am trying to open a Project/Solution in VS 2010. I was able to open the same code successfully in Windows XP, where it gave a dialogue "Temporarily Work Uncontrolled", and on clicking Yes the code loaded and worked fine. But in Windows 7 when I try to open same code it gives me the error:

> "One or more projects in the solution were not loaded correctly"

and no project files are loaded in solution explorer.

Comment: What type of project is it? Some projects, for example XNA, some installers, etc. won't open in some versions of VS, if that version doesn't have built-in support for it (or hasn't been hacked to provide it).

Comment: Refer here:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27705259/error-one-or-more-projects-in-the-solution-were-not-loaded-correctly/37268392#37268392 it works.

Comment: Related -- if there's a message in the "Output" window stating "Some of the properties associated with the solution could not be read", then refer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6190402/visual-studio-warning-some-of-the-properties-associated-with-the-solution-coul

Answer (score 15):

I also faced the same problem. Here is what I did to resolve it:

#### Solution:

Run the solution file with administrator account. ex: Visual studio 2010 in your windows start menu, and right-click, run as administrator. Then, go to the file and open the solution file.

#### Reason for Problem

This occurred because we were creating the virtual directory for the project after copying that project to another location on the same machine. Thus, a virtual conflict occurred. Avoid this situation.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Thanks for your post! Please do not use signatures/taglines in your posts. Your user box counts as your signature, and you can use your profile to post any information about yourself you like. [FAQ on signatures/taglines](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#signatures)

Comment: This will also solve issues with web application projects that are run using iis and not a development webserver (configured in project settings), they require Administrator privileges to load.

Comment: @SimonSvensson I think an alternative is to disable the ACL craziness on Win7+

Answer (score 4):

Copy that project into Visual Studio's project folder , then open it from Visual Studio , now it will be open

I found this technique by myself in Visual Studio 2013

Answer (score 4):

I had this same problem.  The problem for me was in the .sln file.  At the end of the file there were multiple of the following:

GlobalSection(TeamFoundationVersionControl) = preSolution

EndGlobalSection

I deleted the extra ones and the message went away.

I believe the cause of this is when TFS merges different check-ins of the solution or someone does it manually and does it wrong.

Paul

Answer (score 2):

Just resolved this issue on an open source project.  Issue was due to spaces rather than tabs for a line in the .sln file.

https://github.com/fsprojects/Fix/commit/7f613791ed1b35714543eac163d6d9f78605cea8

Answer (score 2):

It usually happens due to VS version. The most straightforward solution is to,

1. **open your Visual Studio and select Open a project or solution**  [image: VisualStudio InitScreen]
2. **then Browse to your project folder. don't select the .sln file.**
3. **browse the solution folder and select .csproj/.vbproj whatever your project type.**[image: Projec tFile]

*Following these steps should load the project without any issues.*

**After loading the project successfully, to solve the .sln file issue. press ctrl+shift+s and replace the .sln file. GOOD LUCK**

Answer (score 1):

### Possible solution (VS 2022)

For me the solution to this problem was to edit the `.sln` file using notepad, the path to the file was not complete.

1. Go to you project folder where the `.sln` file is located
2. Right-click on the file and click on open with; chose notepad
3. check for the path for any mistakes including missing/additional backslash, whitespaces etc.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you don't have the same version of Visual Studio installed as the one in which those projects were created. For example, if the project you're opening is a C++ project, if will fail if you don;t have VS C++ installed. Or you cannot load a project for ASP.NET MVC if you don't have MVC installed.

Open project files in Notepad and look for a Project guid. Then google it and you will find out what project type is not supported by your current installation of VS.

```
<ProjectGuid>{67122503-1A75-40CA-B37E-C0C4C9D6D38B}</ProjectGuid>
```

Answer (score 0):

check if same version of vs2010 is present on win7 and winXP. I suspect project types present on winXP are not installed in win7 and that's why projects are unloaded

Answer (score 0):

I am using Skydrive to share project files between Visual Studio copies on my laptop and PC.

I looked in File Explorer and could see "online-only" against many of the files in my project. Turns out those files are not actually on the computer yet.

There is a setting in the metro skydrive app to force these to be copied over.

I got this info from https://johnfail.wordpress.com/2013/12/10/windows-8-1-making-all-skydrive-files-available-offline/

Answer (score 0):

Go to the Properties Window of the unavailable project showing the project’s path.
File Dialog box will open. Locate project file (.csproj) and click Open.
Finally Reload the Project

Answer (score 0):

This is in VS2017. One of the  .csproj files had a merge conflict from git and I had not resolved it. Resolving that fixed the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I got this on windows 10.

I figured out that the file paths were too long.

My solution was to move the repository to a shorter path.

Answer (score 0):

I was cloning a project ([CleanArchitecture](https://github.com/ardalis/CleanArchitecture)) and wanted to rename the namespace.

1. I cloned the project to `C:\Users\MyUser\source\repos\MyProject`
2. Then I opened `Notepad++`, pressed `Ctrl+F`, went to `Find in Files` and searched for `CleanArchitecture` and replaced with `MyProject`. This changed all occurrences of the project's namespace to `MyProject`, accept the name of the `.csproj` files in `File Explorer`!
3. I had to manually go to `C:\Users\MyUser\source\repos\MyProject` and then change the name of the `.csproj` files.
4. Then in Visual Studio reload the projects.

Answer (score 0):

In my solution, i used c++ and because of that other projects stopped working for me. And I solved it by adding **dotnet** path in environment variables.

System -> System properties -> Environment variables -> Path (**double click**) or **edit** and enter the path where the dotnet is located. C:/Program Files/dotnet
image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/56rEm.png

Answer (score 0):

I just faced the same issue with my .NET MVC project.

the shortest way to solve it is to make sure that the following files name extentoins match exactly to each other:

- .SLN
- .csproj
- .user

## **Your-Project-Name.sln**

[image]

[image]

## this name must be matched with

**Yout-PROJECT-NAME.csproj**

and

**Your-Project.user**

[image]

NOTICE That tha names are NOT match which cause the issue
the correct names:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It can be a build problem.
Build your all project in a proper sequence when you will change in a project.
for ex:- if you change in dblayer then rebuild that and after that build where you are using refrence of that layer.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Mostly these would be caused due to coruptions in solution files so try to edit solution file and do compare with working solutions files u will be able to see some wiered commenrs like ">>>>>>///"***strong text*** this comment will appear when u did merged incorrect like wise . For me the below was get fixed for crashing VS issue by **deleting extra lines** in solution file sample as like below

```
[{051C84DE-7573-495D-8E2A-1DC3F1343B3E} = {F9A2AA02-760A-47B6-A663-BB224CDF86BC}
        {F6D86487-62D1-46F4-8171-28A0635EE97F} = {F9A2AA02-760A-47B6-A663-BB224CDF86BC}
        {7931E22C-6B9F-4FA3-8CEF-7A4FD557C22F} = {F9A2AA02-760A-47B6-A663-BB224CDF86BC}
    EndGlobalSection
    GlobalSection(TestCaseManagementSettings) = postSolution
        CategoryFile = Retalix.StoreOfficeClient8.vsmdi
    EndGlobalSection
EndGlobal]
```

so i deleted the extra lines and added like below then its worked for me

```
{9460EC3D-65F3-44C8-9987-E2303B8D7DC4} = {F9A2AA02-760A-47B6-A663-BB224CDF86BC}
        {051C84DE-7573-495D-8E2A-1DC3F1343B3E} = {F9A2AA02-760A-47B6-A663-BB224CDF86BC}
        {F6D86487-62D1-46F4-8171-28A0635EE97F} = {F9A2AA02-760A-47B6-A663-BB224CDF86BC}
        {7931E22C-6B9F-4FA3-8CEF-7A4FD557C22F} = {F9A2AA02-760A-47B6-A663-BB224CDF86BC}
    EndGlobalSection
EndGlobal
```

Answer (score 0):

I found this solution. I fixed this lines in *.sln file:

BEFORE:

```
GlobalSection(TeamFoundationVersionControl) = preSolution
    SccNumberOfProjects = 36
```

AFTER:

```
GlobalSection(TeamFoundationVersionControl) = preSolution
    SccNumberOfProjects = 34
```

Answer (score 0):

I encounter this problem after I reformat my pc and I resolve this problem. I hope this solution also can fix your problem. I'm using windows 10 with visual studio 2019.

1st- close your application, all running application by visual studio please close
to avoid any bugs.

> > > > [Image_1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o8omF.png)<<<<

2nd- open the windows search button.

> > > > [Image_2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eQsCK.png)<<<<

3rd- search Visual Studio Installer

> > > > [Image_3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8VipI.png)<<<<

4th- just open it. Now if something popup message like say "UPDATE" just press update. The possible I get this error because I install old version of visual studio. After I update I restart my pc and I open again my project.sln no more error.

I hope this solution everyone can help.

Answer (score 0):

1. Close Visual Studio (ensure devenv.exe is not present in the Task Manager)
2. Delete the %USERPROFILE%\AppData\Local\Microsoft\VisualStudio\14.0\ComponentModelCache directory

Answer (score 0):

My solution:

1. Remove Visual Studio
2. Restart your computer
3. Reinstall Visual Studio
4. Open your project

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you are not running the solution file (.sln) from a zipped folder. Must extract all the files from the zipped folder and then run the solution file(.sln).

Answer (score -1):

I also ran into this problem. I came out of it at last with this help:

[An update is available that improves the stability of Visual Studio 2012](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2781514)

The article describes an update that improves the stability of Microsoft Visual Studio 2012. The update also resolves a compatibility issue that may occur when the Microsoft .NET Framework is updated. When this issue occurs, Visual Studio 2012 may not load projects and may crash.

The update is available from Microsoft Update and can also be downloaded from the [Microsoft Download Center](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=36020).

The global version of this update has the file attributes (or later file attributes) that are listed in the following table.

[image: Table of file attributes]

Comment: My version is Visual Studio 2012

Answer (score -2):

Just Repair(Reinstall) your Setup...

Comment: This should be a comment.