# error - One or more projects in the solution were not loaded correctly

Tags: visual-studio-2010

In VisualStudio2010 I changed the name of the project  and the name of the solution.
When I try to open the solution I get this error:

**One or more projects in the solution were not loaded correctly.**

Any idea why I get this error?And how to fix it?

Comment: Did the file path to the project change in any way?

Comment: How did you change the name of the project?  Did you do it inside VS or did you do it in the file system?

Comment: I suggest opening the .sln file in Notepad++ and making sure that the folders where the projects are stored are correct

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try opening the .csproj file in notepad and making sure all references and paths are correct.

Comment: I used VC2012 and found no .csproj file. How come?

Answer (score 3):

In my situation, I had the GlobalSection duplicated in my solution.
I'm using TFS and sometimes it has trouble to merge configuration from multiple developers at the same time.

Open your Solution (.sln) in NotePad++ and look up for this tag and remove one from the duplicated.

```
GlobalSection(TeamFoundationVersionControl) = preSolution
```

You may need to readd the last projects to the solution though.

Answer (score 0):

I got the same trouble when using VC2012. My steps for it are: Control Panel --> Program & Functions --> Right Click on VC2012 --> Select "Recover" --> restart Windows --> re-open the project. It works.
The trouble comes from the damage of VC2012 iteself.

Answer (score 0):

Try to open the application as a website instead of project. In my case the project/application was created as website and when i was trying to open the solution it was giving me the error so i opened the application as a website and the application got loaded.

Answer (score 0):

Check .sln and .csproj files to see if any unused references are added without knowledge

Answer (score 0):

I got the same issue after the code merge. The issue was few closing XML tags were removed. Fix: Open the .csproj file in a notepad and correct the closing tags.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem, the path for the `.csprog` files in the solution some how changed, instead of `\\server\folder` it changed to `\server\folder`.

Try open the `.sln` file using the Notepad and check all the `.csproj` files path.