# "Some of the properties associated with the solution could not be read" Warning in VS 2012

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2012, tfs

When I open solution it gives me warning that "Some of the properties associated with the solution could not be read"

I tried search on the net and I tried solving error from following link: [Visual Studio warning: "Some of the properties associated with the solution could not be read"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6190402/visual-studio-warning-some-of-the-properties-associated-with-the-solution-coul)

I noticed that my solution file has duplicate GlobalSection(TeamFoundationVersionControl) but when i manually removed it, and it stopped giving error but when i tried to add another new project in solution it again added duplicate section of GlobalSection(TeamFoundationVersionControl)

I am using VS 2012 and my solution file contains 48 projects and when i add new project to solution it adds duplicate section which says it has 44 projects. So above mention error continues after I add new project.

All the project in my solution has multiple configuration like Debug, Release etc.

Can anyone help me with this?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Old question, i hope i'll help someone to fix this problem ^_^

The related answer is correct but you need an additional step:

1. Unbind `Solution: yournamesolution.sln` from TFS (`File/Source Control/Advanced/Change Source Control`)
2. Close solution
3. Edit the `.sln` manually by removing all the `GlobalSection(TeamFoundationVersionControl)`
4. Open solution
5. Rebind the solution from the same menu

Source:
[This Blog](http://jeremyronk.wordpress.com/tag/some-of-the-properties-associated-with-the-solution-could-not-be-read/)

Answer (score 0):

For me, it is wrong `SccNumberOfProjects` value because of Merge issue, after I correct it, it is fine again