# Warning Visual Studio: Some of the properties associated with the solution could not be read

Tags: visual-studio-2013, properties, solution

I am posting this as many of the suggested fixes such as looking to see if [[GlobalSection(TeamFoundationVersionControl)]](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6190402/2754403) was duplicated and removing it, renaming the solution to force a rebuild and Rebuilding the solution in visual studio. However none of these have worked. The Solution affected is posted below. (This is really annoying as it doesn't save the build property of my Release configuration either) And I know its related to the `GlobalSection(SolutionConfigurationPlatforms) = preSolution` being duplicated but I don't know how to fix that...

```
Microsoft Visual Studio Solution File, Format Version 12.00
# Visual Studio 2013
VisualStudioVersion = 12.0.40629.0
MinimumVisualStudioVersion = 10.0.40219.1
Project("{FAE04EC0-301F-11D3-BF4B-00C04F79EFBC}") = "DroidKit OnePlus One", "DroidKit OnePlus One\DroidKit OnePlus One.csproj", "{325DC736-70A1-422D-A4B9-441E228C5062}"
EndProject
Global
    GlobalSection(SolutionConfigurationPlatforms) = preSolution
        Debug|Any CPU = Debug|Any CPU
        Debug|Default = Debug|Default
        Release|Any CPU = Release|Any CPU
        Release|Default = Release|Default
    EndGlobalSection
    GlobalSection(ProjectConfigurationPlatforms) = postSolution
        {325DC736-70A1-422D-A4B9-441E228C5062}.Debug|Any CPU.ActiveCfg = Debug|Any CPU
        {325DC736-70A1-422D-A4B9-441E228C5062}.Debug|Any CPU.Build.0 = Debug|Any CPU
        {325DC736-70A1-422D-A4B9-441E228C5062}.Debug|Default.ActiveCfg = Debug|Any CPU
        {325DC736-70A1-422D-A4B9-441E228C5062}.Release|Any CPU.ActiveCfg = Debug|Any CPU
        {325DC736-70A1-422D-A4B9-441E228C5062}.Release|Default.ActiveCfg = Debug|Any CPU
    EndGlobalSection
    GlobalSection(SolutionProperties) = preSolution
        HideSolutionNode = FALSE
    EndGlobalSection
    GlobalSection(SolutionConfigurationPlatforms) = preSolution
        Debug|Any CPU = Debug|Any CPU
        Debug|Default = Debug|Default
        Release|Any CPU = Release|Any CPU
        Release|Default = Release|Default
    EndGlobalSection
    GlobalSection(SolutionConfigurationPlatforms) = preSolution
        Debug|Any CPU = Debug|Any CPU
        Debug|Default = Debug|Default
        Release|Any CPU = Release|Any CPU
        Release|Default = Release|Default
    EndGlobalSection
EndGlobal
```

Comment: Still having no success. As every time I edit it (remove the `GlobalSection(SolutionConfigurationPlatforms) = preSolution`) outside of VS it changes back to what it was...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have a soloution!
So what I did is create another empty project. Copy the whole of the `Global` section and paste it into the broken file. As I don't use Team Sever or Source share it was an easy fix!
The code I copied is below:

```
Global
    GlobalSection(SolutionConfigurationPlatforms) = preSolution
        Debug|Any CPU = Debug|Any CPU
        Debug|x64 = Debug|x64
        Debug|x86 = Debug|x86
        Release|Any CPU = Release|Any CPU
        Release|x64 = Release|x64
        Release|x86 = Release|x86
    EndGlobalSection
    GlobalSection(ProjectConfigurationPlatforms) = postSolution
        {325DC736-70A1-422D-A4B9-441E228C5062}.Debug|Any CPU.ActiveCfg = Debug|Any CPU
        {325DC736-70A1-422D-A4B9-441E228C5062}.Debug|Any CPU.Build.0 = Debug|Any CPU
        {325DC736-70A1-422D-A4B9-441E228C5062}.Debug|x64.ActiveCfg = Debug|Any CPU
        {325DC736-70A1-422D-A4B9-441E228C5062}.Debug|x86.ActiveCfg = Debug|Any CPU
        {325DC736-70A1-422D-A4B9-441E228C5062}.Release|Any CPU.ActiveCfg = Release|Any CPU
        {325DC736-70A1-422D-A4B9-441E228C5062}.Release|Any CPU.Build.0 = Release|Any CPU
        {325DC736-70A1-422D-A4B9-441E228C5062}.Release|x64.ActiveCfg = Release|Any CPU
        {325DC736-70A1-422D-A4B9-441E228C5062}.Release|x86.ActiveCfg = Release|Any CPU
    EndGlobalSection
    GlobalSection(SolutionProperties) = preSolution
        HideSolutionNode = FALSE
    EndGlobalSection
EndGlobal
```